# ZK proof that two short solutions are equal

Tags: lattice-crypto

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ two $m \times n$ matrices defining SIS problems.
Does there exist a zero knowledge proof that two short solutions are the same, i.e.
$$y_1 = A_1 x $$
$$y_2= A_2 x $$
$$ \Vert x \Vert < \beta$$

Comment: You could use a standard [Socialist Millionaire's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires) solution to prove that both parties share the same $x$.

Comment: Do you know that ZK proofs exist for every NP problem? Or are you looking for *practical* ones?

Comment: @fkraiem : I mean practical ones.

Comment: @SEJPM I don't think that this is the question. A single party holds both matrices and wants to prove to someone else that they have the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

This paper [Improved Zero-Knowledge Proofs of Knowledge for the ISIS Problem, and Applications](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/ISIS.pdf) is a good place to start researching. The paper appeared at PKC 2013 so have been peer-reviewed. In addition, there is an upcoming paper at CRYPTO 2016 which looks very related [How to prove knowledge of small secrets](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/538.pdf).